# Using variables and Http header field names with Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, http-headers, httpclient, request-headers

I'm trying to use a variable for the header field name in a Http request. The field name can change so I make a call to get the name of the field and need to place the response into the Http request as a header field name. When i try the code below I get an error

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  this.variableNameForHeader : this.variableNameForValue
});
```

The editor gives an error where I have "this.variableNameForHeader" it says there should be a ":" instead of the period "." and where i have the ":" between the variable names it says i should have a comma ","

Comment: You need to give the error.

Comment: it's not really a console.log error it's an error in the editor. Where I have "this.variableNameForHeader" it says there should be a ":" instead of the period "." and where i have the ":" between the variable names it says i should have a comma ","

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the semicolon at the end ";" .

Answer (score 0):

Yay I figured it out once i searched instead for "use variable as key javascript". I need to wrap the variable in square brackets "[]" and just like that, balance is restored.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  [this.variableNameForHeader]: this.variableNameForValue
});
```